# How can I redirect URLs beginning with common path using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm facing difficuty in redirecting urls using .htaccess

**Current url is:** abc.com/product/games/product-name

**I want to 301 redirect to:** abc.com/games/product-name

Similarly, if any url has product/ in beginning it should be redirected to one without it.

Another example:

**Current URL:** abc.com/product/toys/teddy

**Redirect to URL:** abc.com/toys/teddy

I tried doing the following:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L] 
    </ifmodule>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rule file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Your current rule looks fine. What is the problem with that?

Comment: @anubhava, I tried my best to help OP, when I asked what's not working I got response nothing is shown or nothing is working hence I had to delete my answer then here.

Answer (score 0):

Every url starts with a "/" so try changing the rewrite rule as following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/product/(.*) /$1 [R=301,NC,L] 
</ifmodule>
```